# Store dynamic dropdown options with Python and Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to store address values generated by a postcode lookup and then create a list that I can use the python Random module to select a random value using random.choice

Scenario:

Enter postcode, click 'Search' - dropdown list is dynamically populated with available options.

I'm using a dictionary to store my form values as xpaths and then using the webdriver to `find_elements_by_xpath` or `find_element_by_xpath`.

Code looks something like this (not properly formatted, just reference):

```
__author__ = 'scott'

from selenium import webdriver
import random

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.somerandomsite')

formFields = {'postcode' : "//INPUT[@id='postcode']",
        'county' : "//SELECT[@id='address']/option"}

pcList = ['BD23 1DN', 'BD20 0JZ']

#picks a random postcode from pcList#
driver.find_element_by_xpath(formFields['postcode']).send_keys(random.choice(pcList))

driver.find_elements_by_xpath(formFields['county'])

#####now need to store the values from county and select a random option from the list######

driver.close()
```

Using the random module on my postcodes isn't a problem.

If anyone can give some guidance or point me in a direction to take for reference it would be much appreciated - I'm only a noob to Selenium and Python - made steady progress but seem to be going round in circles on this problem - my first issue was using `find_element_by_xpath` a simple 's' missing off 'element' threw me for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Select`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) class provided by the python selenium bindings out-of-the-box - it is a nice abstraction layer over `select->option` HTML structures:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# initialize the select instance
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('address'))

# get the list of options and choose a random one
options = [o.text for o in select.options]
option = random.choice(options)

# select it
select.select_by_visible_text(option)
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe. Exactly the thing I was looking for. Really appreciate this.